# How can I find all of the solution's assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, envdte

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension/add-in and I want to find the names of all of the assemblies created from the projects in the current solution.

I don't have any technological limitation - I can use DTE, MEF or whatever else that gets the job done.

Comment: What do you mean with "all assemblies in the solution" ?  All project-outputs or all assemblies referenced by the outputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find an answer - using DTE:

```
var projects = dte.Solution.Projects;
foreach (Project project in projects)
{
    if (project.Properties != null)
    {
        var assemblyName = project.Properties.Item("AssemblyName").Value.ToString();
    }
}
```